# Generating random URL for each Thank You page

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm fiddeling around with a problem and cant find a solution. What is basically needed is that I have a site where download button inserts a random code in the end of the URL, example

```
<a href="/thanks.php?uq=<?php echo rand_string( 5 ); ?>" target="_blank">Thank you</a>
```

But currently the url will look like `xx.mydomain.com/thanks.php?uq=2js98` or etc, what I would like to do, is that the url would look `xx.mydomain.com/thanks2js98.php` or just `xx.mydomain.com/thanks2js98`

I have tried all the info I can find, but I think I'm not at home with all the code :(

Comment: this is probably url rewrite issues...

Comment: Use .htaccess and url rewrite http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: You will need to update your anchor's href to be `/thanks<?php echo rand_string( 5 ); ?>.php` in addition to using .htaccess to rewrite the URL from `/thanks2js98.php` to `/thanks.php?uq=2js98`.

Comment: i tried with .htaccess but I cant put my finger on why it didnt work. Basically the code i used is RewriteEngine On

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+uq/index\.php\?uq=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /vic/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^vic/([0-9]+)/?$ /uq/index.php?uq=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: @SamSullivan - I actually want the link to be thanks{randomcode}.php

BTW! - Previous .htaccess code is from another thread here that is quite similar and I tried to modify it, but it didnt work

Comment: Can't you modify your PHP code to this: `<a href="/thanks<?php echo rand_string( 5 ); ?>.php" target="_blank">Thank you</a>`

Comment: @anubhava - this way it would generate random file, but the file would not exist.

I have gotten this far - 
`RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
`

So now im able to remove the .php at the end, so now my url is looking like this `xx.mydomain.com/thanks` but now i need to add random code behind it `xx.mydomain.com/thanks{CODEHERE}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Modify your PHP code to this:

```
<a href="/thanks<?php echo rand_string( 5 ); ?>.php" target="_blank">Thank you</a>
```

**Step 2:**

Put this code your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(thanks)[0-9]+(\.php)$ /$1$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I added the codes but I got 404 Not Found error, so in `index.php` I changed the href link you gave. thanks.php is in the folder aswell and .htaccess was changed to the text you handed me. it is in doc root

PS! - output is `xx.mydomain.com/thanks9rjkV.php` but gives `404 Not Found` error

Comment: I had already tested this code. Using this when I opened a link `/thanks12345.php` it loaded content from `/thanks.php`.

Comment: PPS! - I found out that `xx.mydomain.com/thanks12345.php` works, but not `xx.mydomain.com/thanks1234t.php`

Problem is that mine loads letters into the random code aswell

PS! I changed my code - removed letters and its working now! Thanks!